# Codeigniter redirection

Tags: codeigniter

Hi I created a codeigniter project but when I click on a link to one of my functions, example add user, I get redirected to the main page of my local host XAMPP installation instead of being taken to the correct application url. What can be the problem? Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your code.

Comment: show some code? which CI are you using? maybe error is regarding your htaccess file.

Comment: Htacces: http://pastebin.com/PBwLTDtF

Config: http://pastebin.com/Luj1eXBj

View: http://pastebin.com/4F14TAUx

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the link (can you show us the code)? If you are not using the URLHelper take a look at [urlHelper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

I am just guessing, but maybe you are missing the Controller name (you have to load the UrlHelper), e.g.:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('/name_of_the_controller/method_to_invoke'); ?>">Link to the controllers method</a>
```

or (see Jordan Arsenault's comment below on the usage of the `site_url` call for better performance):

```
<?= anchor('/name_of_the_controller/method_to_invoke', 'Link to the controllers method'); ?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In general, using `site_url();` for anchors is asking the server to perform more work than it needs to because there could be hundreds of links on a page. It's better to just write `<a href='controller/function'>My Link</a>` and establish a base url a single time using the HTML <base> element: `<base href="<?= site_url();?>"/>` In the head of the document   :) Just an optimization tip!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the base URL in the CI configuration? file `projectname/application/config/config.php`? This might be the problem... I guess your project isn't on the webroot, but your base URL is missing the `/projectname/` part.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/projectname/';
```